# Why does "not a one" sound incorrect, but "not a single one" sounds okay?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions

To me, *not a one* sounds incorrect, but *not a single one* sounds okay. Is there any grammar to support why my ears weep at the sound of the former phrase, but not the latter?

Comment: There is not one thing wrong with either, no, not a one.

Comment: Both sound fine to me.

Comment: Not a one! not a single one: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+a+one%2Cnot+a++single+one&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20a%20one%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20a%20single%20one%3B%2Cc0

Comment: 'Not a one' is just rarer than 'not a single one' nowadays. It's thus actually used in order to create more of a jarring sensation, for emphasis in poetry say.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, very interesting. Mission accomplished. Although *not a single one* should be even more emphasis since "a" + "single" + "one" has 3x the kick instead of 2x.

Comment: Yes, and I've checked. My intuitions were wrong. 'Not a one' apparently became the commoner version in the 60s - 80s, according to Google Ngrams. But it's still my perception that 'not a one'  jars more. Both are totally acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

The statistics at COCA are very close: around 15 for each.

However, **"not a one"** is seen mostly (80%) in fiction. My guess this is caused by authors wishing to be "natural" by clipping/eliding :-)

**"Not a single one"** is seen 40-50% in speech. Perhaps because of the stress that can be put on "single."