# Is it grammatically correct to start a sentence with "Not a +noun"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is it grammatically correct to start a sentence with "Not a +noun"?
For example, "Not a woman held a presidential cabinet position in the US until 1933, when Frances Perkins became secretary of labor." Is this sentence grammatically correct? WOuld native speakers prefer to say "No woman held a presidential cabinet position in the US until 1933, when Frances Perkins became secretary of labor."
If both are acceptable, what are the differences?
Thank you.

Comment: Related: [*Why does “not a one” sound incorrect, but “not a single one” sounds okay?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238881/why-does-not-a-one-sound-incorrect-but-not-a-single-one-sounds-okay)

Comment: The answer to your question seems to be that it is unidiomatic/awkward in an active voice clause, but ok if the clause is passive. Consider “Not a peep was heard/Not a shot was fired/Not a word was written against him/Not a drop was wasted/Not a hand was raised” etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting a sentence with that phrase may be grammatically alright, but it is highly unusual in most contexts. For example, take this line from *[The Night Before Christmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Visit_from_St._Nicholas)* (1823), where the construction serves as the subject to a verb phrase:

> 'Twas the night before Christmas, when all through the house
>
> **Not a creature** was stirring, not even a mouse (...)

This sounds old-fashioned to most English speakers today, who would be more likely to say *no one was stirring* or *no creature was stirring* if they were not reading a Christmas story.

If you run a search for this construction, you're likely to see certain set idioms, like *[not a peep](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+a+peep+from+you)*, which can appear at the start of a sentence:

> But **not a peep** of concern can be heard. ([source](https://www.jonathanpollard.org/2005/011905.htm))

> **Not a peep** was heard from the students, least of all my troublesome student. ([source](https://mnaves.wordpress.com/tag/john-berger/))

Outside of that, you'd be hard-pressed to find results for *not a NOUN PHRASE*. For instance, running a search for "not a woman _v" in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) generated 45 results. Out of that list, none started a sentence, and most results were actually versions of *whether or not a woman VERBS*, e.g.,

[image]

If you want to use a similar construction for emphasis, *not one NOUN PHRASE* is more generative:

> **Not one woman** has told her that she thought abortion was okay, she adds. ([source](https://www.esquire.com/news-politics/a23771/abortion-ministry-of-dr-willie-parker-0914/))

> **Not one woman** is visible among the hundreds of vendors except tiny "Annie," who peddles cigarettes at $3.50 a pack off her shopping cart, covered with old newspapers. (source)

> **Not one woman** spoke to me at that party last night the whole evening. ("Oh Vey, You're Gay," *The Nanny* (1995, TV Show)

Otherwise, I would strongly suggest using "No woman held ..." which would be the most common usage.